# How to file upload mvc5 on cpanel server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, cpanel

I've created a project in visual studio on MVC5. As you guys can see in pictures bellow index.cshtml is in Views/Home/index.cshtml! So how can I upload it on cpanel server. As you guys know on server we need an index.html file to link! I don't know how to handle that, let me know if further details or project code is required... Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KveEx.png)

Comment: I don't think you know how .Net MVC projects work. Changes are if you have a cpanel, you have the wrong type of hosting. You're not going to be able to host your .Net projects on a Linux host, which is just one of the issues you have....

Comment: Isn't there any way to make my project working on it?

Comment: Not right now. At some point, containers like dockers might let that work. You need a windows host like https://www.phi9.com/hosting.html (asp plans). Given that you didn't know you need a Windows host and it doesn't seem like you know how MVC works, I'd really suggest reading up on MVC/.Net first

Answer (score 0):

it will not work on cPanel hosting because its a Linux platform that will not support for your programming type. so take another hosting of a windows server if you want manged hosting than go with windows plesk hosting providers.

Comment: Thanks! I just got plesk hosting providers! Now please can you tell me how to upload this mvc5 website on plesk?